# New computer turns off after few minutes of using it. Powers back on. PSU?

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, power-supply

**These are the problems I have experienced:**

- Computer turns off while trying to install Windows 10 for the first time.
- After many tries, I was able to install Windows but can´t use it as computer turns off before the login screen
- Was able to install Ubuntu Linux and can use it a few minutes before the same thing happens

**My built has the following SPECS:**

- Msi Mag Vampiric 010 (Case)
- Corsair TX 750W (CMPSU-750TX)
- Gigabyte Intel Z490 Aorus Elite AC
- Intel Core i7-10700K
- DDR4 16gb 3200mhz Dimm HyperX Fury Black x 2 (32 GB)
- SSD 500GB Kingston A2000, M.2 2280, NVMe PCIe
- WD Black WD1001FALS 1TB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s
- BE QUIET! PURE LOOP 280MM - NA0000050186

Everything is new except the PSU which I bought 11 years ago and the WD Black drive.

The PSU works fine in my old computer.

The motherboard has 3 ATX power connectors (24 pin, 8 pin and 4 pin).

My power supply has only a 24 pin and 8 pin, so only those are connected.

I left the 4 pin alone. (see image)

[image]

**I have done the following (with no success):**

- I am able to enter the BIOS and edit settings.
- I have flashed the BIOS with different versions.
- I have tried different combinations of RAM sticks (I have 2)

  - A1 - 16GB (both of them separately)
  - A1 - 16GB / B1 - 16 GB
  - A2 - 16GB (both of them separately)
  - A2 - 16GB / B2 - 16 GB
- CPU Temperature has not gone over 50ºC
- Removed WD Black and tried installing OS on Kingston M.2
- Removed Kingston M.2 and tried installing OS WD Black

**Questions:**

- *Is there a "y-cable" splitter from 8 pin to 8 pin and 4 pin or something like that?*
- *Could I use one of the PCIe or SATA power cables with some sort of adapter?*
- *Is it mandatory to connect the 4 pin cable?* (I have read all sorts of opinions but they usually says it's ok not to unless you overclock the CPU.)
- I will try another PSU just in case.
- Any BIOS settings I should consider tweaking?
- *Is there another thing I should try?*
- *Any bootable USB with diagnosis tools I could use?*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: W10 install will auto reboot several times during installation, more details on exactly what you are experiencing.

Comment: The computer reboots before I can finish the first step (window) of the installation wizard... I can leave the computer rebooting all day. It is not part of the installation procedure. Actually it seems more like a power-off and restarting... not a reboot.

Comment: Corsair PSUs are notorious for having CapXon capacitors in them, which are known to fail.  I would check that first and/or swap with another PSU as an easy check if possible.  PSUs are the equivalent of your house's foundation.  Unsexy, but critical.

Comment: It can be a lot of things. Cooling, PSU are prime suspects, but so are less obvious components. Disconnect as much as ppssible, including extra drives. The weirdest I ever encountered was a similar issue due to a Bluray drive.

Comment: Simple solution: buy a new PSU, problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You motherboard manual isn't very clear on this point but it looks to me you can either use the 2x2 or the 2x4 connector. You don't need to connect them both.

First check if nothing is overheating. Are all your fans running?

If that is OK it is most likely the PSU.
Either it is faulty (as already said in the comments these older Corsair PSU are prone to capacitor issues), but the fault may not trigger when used in another system (or only show there under heavy load).

Or your setup draws too much power on one of the powerrails of the PSU causing something to overheat inside the PSU or trip a fuse.
This is typical for older PSU's. Newer motherboards, especially those with fancy on-board power-regulators like yours tend to draw a lot more 12V power than 5V power, while older PSU's typically can supply more 5V than 12V.
If that is the case it may help to re-arrange the distribution of devices across the various power-outputs of the PSU to get a better balance across the rails, but since your motherboard draws the vast majority of the power and you can't change that this will most likely not help.

Comment: OK, so a friend lent me his PSU and I only connected the 8-pin and everything worked fine. I will go ahead and buy a new one or can I get the capacitors replaced?.

Comment: @supercoco In theory you can replace the caps. If you are handy with a soldering iron, if you can figure out with size caps you need (they are often unlabeled) and if you can actually order the proper replacements somewhere. And you still end up with a old PSU in which other components may be (or become) unreliable. Buying a new one is the practical option. I personally have the skill-set to do such a replacement and I wouldn't bother spending that time and effort on a $100 PSU.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe that the CPU is not getting enough power due to the 4 pin connector not being connected.
Try underclock (if that is an option) the CPU to see if the system is more stable.

You can split the existing 8 pin connector but you need to check if the power supply provides enough current on those pins for both connectors.

Comment: So I bought a Y cable that splits into two 8 pin connectors. I was able to plug one of them to the 4 pin connector and the other to the 8 pin connector. The computer still turns off.  Maybe the amount of current through that cable is not enough or I just need to change the PSU.